# Fragment does not show after clicking recyclerview item

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager inside a an activity. Everything works as intended

this is inside the `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` of the activity

```
myPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
viewPager.setAdapter(myPagerAdapter);
```

I have one fragment that contains the RecyclerView that lists some items. Here is what supposed to happen:
When I tap on an item, it should display DetailsFragment.
This is my code for when the user taps on an item:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
Fragment indi=DetailsFragment.newInstance();
ft.add(R.id.(Fragment Container ID), indi);
ft.show(indi).commit();
```

I have tried this:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
Fragment indi=DetailsFragment.newInstance();
ft.replace(R.id.(Activity Container ID), indi);
ft.show(indi).commit();
```

And this:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
Fragment indi=DetailsFragment.newInstance();
ft.replce(R.id.(Container Fragment ID), indi);
ft.show(indi).commit();
```

Android will create the fragment because I have set up a Log in the `onResume()` method inside DetailsFragment but it does not show
All of my attempts give me the same result the fragment is created but nothing shows up.
**And no error log**

Comment: Please, show your layout xml with ids (Container Fragment ID, Activity Container ID, Fragment Container ID).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
Fragment indi=DetailsFragment.newInstance();
ft.replace(R.id.container, indi);
ft.commit();
```

when `R.id.container` is the resource id of the layout that you want to remove in order to put `DetailsFragment` in its place. You can use a simple `FrameLayout` in your main_activity.xml (or any other activity you're in):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        // you can put anything else here

</LinearLayout>
```